# Next js and graphql on demand revalidation in app router

Tags: apollo, next.js13

[image]

I am creating next.js application with app router and appollo graphql, for graphql query i have used appolo [@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support) module, in next.js app router they have on demand validation pass in fetch api as per above screenshot, how can i pass same thing in appolo for on demand validation ?

i want to revalidate with webbook.

i want to use Apollo graphql with next.js app router with on demand validation that next.js providing. i want to revalidate with webbook.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass fetch options to your queries:
[fetchOptions example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tBKi.png)

Check the full conde and explanation here: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/how-to-use-apollo-client-with-next-js-13#next-js-cache-and-apollo

Answer (score 0):

I aslo try to use this.

It seems possible to revalidate on a route segment.

```
export const revalidate = 3600 // revalidate at most every hour
```

Another alternative, is to fetch directly without apollo...

```
const data = await executeGraphQL({
    query: query,
    variables: {
        channel: "default-channel",
        first: 12,
    })

});


const result = await fetch(endpoint, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        ...headers,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: query.toString(),
        ...(variables && { variables }),
    }),
    cache,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revalidate with webhook you need to create a route that can manage it.

```js
// app/revalidate/route.ts
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const searchParams = new URL(request.url).searchParams;
  const url = searchParams.get('url');
  revalidatePath(url || '/');
  return new Response(`Revalidating ${url}`, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  });
}
```

then call your-website-url/revalidate?url=url/that/needs/to/be/invalidated.

More info on https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath